# Query Code Joining Issues

Tags: mysql, join

[Final Query Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zTAo.png) - What the final table should look like.
[Pubs Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8CCw.png) - I did not include the author_id which needs to be changed to SSN.

I am very new to this - like three weeks into this class. I'm struggling to wrap my brain around the concepts but it looks like there is a wealth of information on stack overflow I need to keep reading....it would help if I were actually using a database on a regular basis in a real life situation right now. Here is my query I keep coming up with an error on - possible I am making beginner mistakes I'm not seeing or understanding. I want to understand and get this down before it gets harder.

```
USE pubs
SELECT DISTINCT authors_id as SSN
FROM authors
SELECT au_lname, au_fname as fullname
FROM authors
INNER JOIN author
WHERE royalsched = <50
```

I'm getting an error message - incorrect syntax near the word where, msg 156, level 15 state 1 line 7

The question is: Select the unique author id as ssn, the lastname and firstname separated by a comma (smith, joe) as Fullname from the authors table joined on the titleauthor table where the royaltyper is less than 50. Order the query by the fullname. I get that I need to append the values of the fields together (concatenate) by using the + symbol and I know that I need to join them - just not sure if I'm headed in the right direction or not. Is there a place you can check your queries like validator online (to show where you've missed stuff?)

**Update 10/6/16:** 
Tried it again. This is my reasoning: join the tables (INNERJOIN?) bring together the first name and last name (field 1 + field 2) althoughthis is where you were saying I need to do something different. This is what I came up with but it is not working: (authors_id is what it is called in the database so it needs to be changed to SSN, au_lname and au_fname need to be combined into one column as FullName) then it needs to show the royaltyper is less than 50.

SELECT authors_id = SSN FROM authors AS INNER JOIN ON au_lname + au_fname WHERE royaltyper = <50

Answer (score 0):

Your join is missing an `ON` clause to tell how authors and (title?)author are related.  For instance, `ON authors.id=titleauthor.author_id`.

That's what it is expecting where it sees `WHERE`.  (mysql also supports a `USING ()` syntax instead of `ON`.  But one or the other must be specified for non-CROSS joins.)

To concatenate in mysql, you use `CONCAT`, not `+`.  E.g.:

```
concat(au_lname,', ',au_fname) as Fullname
```

Comment: Yes, the wording my prof used confused me because she said - if you have the need to append the values of the fields together (i.e. concatenate) this can be accomplished by using the '+' symbol in sql. For instance if I wanted to append the value of field 1 to field 2 I would use field 1 + field 2.

Comment: some sql database systems use `+` for string concatenation; mysql does not; in mysql it converts both operands to numbers and adds those.  If your prof was talking about mysql, she made a mistake.

Comment: so where is it that one changes the authors_id to SSN if you cannot have two select statements? That's what I'm confused about.

Comment: oh, those aren't two separate statements?  show more (in your question): what columns are in the tables?  what results do you want?

Comment: Ok - so I know it is supposed to look like this:

Comment: Was there supposed to be more in that comment t?

Comment: Sorry about that. The results of the query will yield only 6 records, and have the following two columns entitled: SSN and Fullname and no repeating records. So, am I correct in saying that this is an Inner join but I am adding a new field - distinct?

Comment: Pretty sure you want an inner join, yes, but you still haven't shown what columns are in the tables.  I don't know what you mean by adding a new field or by distinct.